# Date format is not correct as per locale

Tags: python, date, locale

I need locale date format in python. As you can check the python datetime [module link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for %x format the example clearly says that my date result is from None locale. But in the code below locale is printed as en_US.

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime

default_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]
print(default_locale)  #en_US

date_val = "2021-12-20"
date1 = datetime.strptime(date_val, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(date1) #2021-12-20
print(date1.strftime("%x"))  #12/20/21
# Expected 12/20/2021
```

I have tried babel too but it produces the same result:

```
from babel.dates import format_date
date_val = "2021-12-20"
default_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()[0]  #en_US
val_date = format_date(date_val, format='short', locale=default_locale)
print(val_date)  #12/20/21
```

So what is the missing piece

Comment: Default locale does not mean the locale in use. Use `local.setlocale()` to set the locale.

Comment: but isnt default locale used when %x format is used ??

Comment: @VPfB using local.setlocale() did  fix the date formatting thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in the [locale docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getdefaultlocale):

> According to POSIX, a program which has not called setlocale(LC_ALL,
> '') runs using the portable 'C' locale. Calling setlocale(LC_ALL, '')
> lets it use the default locale as defined by the LANG variable.

So if you don't do anything, you'll get the basic `'C'` locale.

If you call `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`, the program switches to the default locale determined by the environment. If you want to know which one it is, use `getdefaultlocale`.

And the third option is to set the locale explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from above comments @VPfB provided solution fixed the issue but the another
catch when setting locale is on windows the locale value is **English_United States.1252** not **en_US**

```
local.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"English_United States.1252")
```